# regarding joomla template installation

Tags: joomla

I have an error message while installing a  template in joomla m using wamp 2.1 and joomla 3.0.3 .
the error code is

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method JRegistry::getValue() in C:\wamp\www\Joomla\templates\blackwhite\icetools\default.php on line 284

Comment: did u sure that ur template support joomla 3.0.3?

Answer (score 3):

JRegistry::getValue() was previously deprecated and removed in Joomla 3.x. It should be changed to JRegistry::get() instead. Please see http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2#JRegistry